# How to add dynamic keys in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, date, dynamic

I don't have a glue how to solve my problem.
I want to produce an array like this one:

```
$days = array( 
            02=>array(NULL,'request_day'), 
            03=>array(NULL,'request_day'), 
            04=>array(NULL,'request_day'), 
            05=>array(NULL,'request_day'), 
        );
```

I need this to display the requested days on a calendar. Now I deal with a problem that I'm not able to generate dynamic keys (the the keys 02/03/04/05 as stated above).

My code looks like that:

```
    $days = array();
    $array_framework = array(NULL,'request_day');
    foreach ( $period as $dt )
    {
        echo $dt->format("d");
        $blub = $dt->format("d");
        $days[] = array($blub=>$array_framework);
    }
```

$period is an array which represent the days between two dates, and $blub prints out one day after another.

Comment: Have you tried array_push ?

Comment: Daniel is right, use array_push, right now you made 3-dimensional array.

Comment: can I define my key with array_push?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is what you want to do. If you have problems with the array keys being turned from strings (e.g. 03) into integers (e.g. 3) then cast the array key to a string.

```
$days = array();
$array_framework = array(NULL,'request_day');
foreach ( $period as $dt )
{
    $days[$dt->format("d")] = $array_framework;
}
```

Comment: thanks but that don't really works. it produces `Array ( [04] => Array ( [0] => [1] => request_day ) [05] => Array ( [0] => [1] => request_day ) [06] => Array ( [0] => [1] => request_day ) [07] => Array ( [0] => [1] => request_day ) )`

Comment: That's what you wanted. You can ignore the 0 and 1 keys in the sub-arrays.

Comment: To verify that add a `print_r($array_framework)` in the line after you declare it.

Comment: ok thanks. that array is now what it should be but the result is not as expected... but it's not the array's fault

Answer (score 1):

Remove `$days[] = array($blub=>$array_framework);` and use:

```
$days[$blub] = $array_framework;
```

Comment: thanks but that don't really works. it produces `Array ( [04] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [1] => request_day ) ) [05] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [1] => request_day ) ) [06] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [1] => request_day ) ) [07] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [1] => request_day ) ) )`

Comment: ok thanks. that array is now what it should be but the result is not as expected... but it's not the array's fault